# How do I get the $num_rows variable to work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Everything in my code works but $num_results...

Book-O-Rama Search Results

## Book-O-Rama Search Results

```
    //create short variable names
    $searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];
    $searchterm=$_POST['searchterm'];
    $searchterm=trim($searchterm);

    if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
        echo 'You have not entered search details. Please go back and try again.';
        exit;
    }
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $searchtype = addslashes($searchtype);
        $searchterm = addslashes($searchterm);
    }

    include "../common/inc/db_connect_books.php";

    //$db = new mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'books');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE ".$searchtype." LIKE '%".$searchterm."%'"
        or die(mysql_error());

    $result = $dbh->query($sql);

    $num_results = $result->num_rows;

    echo '<p>Number of books found: '.$num_results.'</p>';

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo '<p><b>'.($i+1).'. Title: ';
        echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['title']));
        echo '</b><br>Author: ';
        echo stripslashes($row['authors']);
        echo '<br>ISBN: ';
        echo stripslashes($row['isbn']);
        echo '<br>Price: ';
        echo stripslashes($row['price']);
        echo '</p>';

        $result->free();
        $dbh->close();
    }
?>
```

PLease help

Comment: Thanks code duck... simple is best..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use mysql_num_rows http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";

?>
```

Comment: You can't use the mysql_* functions with PDO, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a guess you're using some type of MySQL wrapper? If so change `$num_results = $result->num_rows;` to `$num_results = $dbh->num_rows;` assuming that num_rows is a method of `$dbh`. If this doesn't work, then you could use `$num_results = count($result);`.

I'm not sure what wrapper you're using so I have no idea if the above code will work.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest simply

```
$num_results = count($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are missing the "$" in front of num_rows (i.e. it should be "$num_rows"). That could be it.

Comment: It's object property syntax, actually, not a variable. So if $result had a num_rows property (which it doesn't, I guess) that would be the correct form, no $.